# component scope service with injected messages

Tags: tapestry

I am aware that there is something special about tapestry services/resources such as Request, Messages etc which are only available in the context of a component render.

I need to create a service which makes heavy use of the messages store and is available only in the scope of a component render.

Can someone explain how I can configure this service correctly so that I can create it with the appropriated Messages object each time it is used?

eg (i know this wouldn't work):

```
public class MyServiceImpl
{
    @Inject private Messages messages;

    @Override
    public String getSomeMessage(Object someParameter)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

and then i could use it like so:

```
public class MyComponent
{
    @Inject
    @Parameter
    private MyService myService;
}
```

tml:

```
<p>${myService.getSomeMessage('someParameter')}</p>
```

Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the best solution was to pass the messages object into another service's methods as an argument:

```
@Inject @Property private MyService myService;
@Inject @Property private Messages messages;

<t:output value="myService.getSomething(messages)" />
```